# «Сеть косметологий», «Сеть стоматологий». Допустимо ли?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Подобные словосочетания являются ли приемлемыми?

Answer (score 2):

Я думаю, что сеть стоматологий - тоже не слишком удачно.
Но это хотя бы оправдано тем, что "стоматология" уже стало привычно в значении "отделение", "заведение" и проч. Но вот насчет множественного числа в таком значении - не уверен.

В отношении же "косметологии" - как-то совсем зыбко по всем позициям. В рекламно-информационном тексте я бы его еще принял, в ином - поостерегся.

А чем хуже "косметологическая сеть"? Или тут двусмысленность получается?

Comment: Да,смысл чуть другой получается.Спасибо

Answer (score 2):

Что можно увидеть в словаре:
КОСМЕТОЛОГИЯ, -и; ж. [от греч. kosmētikē - искусство украшать и logos - учение]
Наука о лечебной косметике.

СТОМАТОЛОГИЯ, -и; ж. [от греч. stoma (stmatos) - рот и logos - учение]
Раздел медицины, изучающий болезни зубов.

С одной стороны, косметологические салоны и стоматологические клиники по правилам русского языка не могут называться косметологиями и стоматологиями, с другой стороны, потребность в таких названиях есть. Но пока эти слова не получили второго значения, они должны употребляться только в разговорной речи.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ